# (Re?)Install Ubuntu on a Dell laptop that had Ubuntu preinstalled

Tags: system-installation

I have Dell Laptop that is 15 5567 7th Generation. So it was maybe pre-installed as Dell says and I can see in the product information that this laptop is Ubuntu built in and based not Windows.

So I want to get my Ubuntu OS again. How can I do that?

Comment: do you mean you are looking for an Ubuntu .iso file that came pre-installed with your laptop? 
If yes, kindly edit your question so that we can assist accordingly.

Comment: See if https://askubuntu.com/questions/926204/whats-the-difference-between-vanilla-ubuntu-and-the-dell-oem-version helps.

Comment: Its edited and set properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that laptop comes with ubuntu 16.04 to download that OS see this   [download page](http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/) you will probably want the "ubuntu-16.04.4-desktop-i386.iso" but you will have to decide that based on your needs and computer.

To install the OS see this [tutorial](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#2) there are many other tutorials online if you prefer a different one.

**Edit:**
It looks like there is some confusion over whether Dell uses its own version of Ubuntu or not (see comments). Either way, they have a Ubuntu iso 12.04 on their website see [12.04-OSP1](http://linux.dell.com/files/ubuntu/precise/12.04-OSP1/)

**Edit2:**

OP just wants to install Ubuntu.
To set up just Dual-Boot just follow this guide: [How to Install Ubuntu Alongside With Windows in Dual-Boot | tecmint.com](https://www.tecmint.com/install-ubuntu-16-04-alongside-with-windows-10-or-8-in-dual-boot/)

To just Install Ubuntu see.
[How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Comment: Although OP didn't make it clear in the question, I'm pretty sure OP's looking for Dell OEM Ubuntu iso tailored for their "Dell Inspirion 1567 7th Gen", not the generic Ubuntu iso.

Comment: @pomsky While I think you are correct according to the [Dell forms](https://www.dell.com/community/Linux-General/Inspiron-15-3521-DELL-OEM-Ubuntu-image/td-p/4057902) "we do not have a special OEM release of Ubuntu 12.04 LTS". I assume this applies to whichever Ubuntu OP has.

Comment: It seems the tech-support person who made the comment is not at all well-informed. I found a customised 12.04 iso just after a few minutes of googling: http://linux.dell.com/files/ubuntu/precise/12.04-OSP1/dell-12.04.2_20130822_0809.iso

Comment: Interesting, looks like you might right, I wonder if that is just the same OS or if they actually have it optimized for Dell laptops.  I guess OP can use it either way. Though that file looks like it has not been updated since 2013.

Comment: I am really confused guys, I don't know which Ubuntu to install in my Dell laptop. See the main question guys its been updated by me.

Comment: @MohammadAli do you want to have the exact same Ubuntu? If you are just a typical desktop user you can install any version of Ubuntu and you probably won't notice a much of a difference if any. There won't be any problems running a generic version of Ubuntu on your computer (i'm running 16.04 on my Dell PC I could just as easily run 12.04).  If there is a reason you would like the old version that came on your computer please explain why.

Bottom line, your computer can run pretty much any version of Ubuntu. I suggest the latest stale version unless you need your old version.

Comment: Well the things is I just found in my Support Drivers and Tools of my laptop there that is it supports Drivers for Windows 10, 64 bit and Ubuntu 16.04. So does it mean that my laptop had Ubuntu 16.04 as original?

Comment: @MohammadAli No it does not mean that. My understanding is that that is there because on Windows 10 Microsoft enables users to use the Linux command line in Windows (which is awesome). It is not enabled by default but there are lots of guides on how to do this.  I'm surprised that Ubuntu appears on the system before it's enabled but it seems to be the case.

Comment: @MohammadAli Have you used Ubuntu desktop on this laptop?

Comment: No. I didn't use.

Comment: @MohammadAli do you want to have the Desktop Ubuntu or do you just want the text-based command line access?

Comment: I think the best one is Desktop Ubuntu right?

Comment: @MohammadAli it is not a matter of best, it's a matter of your use case. But I'm certain you want the desktop version.

Comment: Desktop then bro. Give me the links and instructions as well.

Comment: @MohammadAli you have 2 options, create a Dual-Boot setup which would allow you to pick if you want to run windows or Ubuntu every time your computer starts.  OR you can destroy your windows install and just have Ubuntu.  For your use I would suggest having the Dual-Boot setup. if that's what you want follow this guide. https://www.tecmint.com/install-ubuntu-16-04-alongside-with-windows-10-or-8-in-dual-boot/

Comment: That is for downloading Ubuntu 16.04 so its the latest Ubuntu? And I should select the 64bit right the "64-bit PC (AMD64) desktop image" ?

Comment: @MohammadAli 16.04  is not the latest but it is what  I suggest you use. If you have a 64-bit computer download the 64-bit option.

Comment: Well can I run softwares like, Adobe CC, Google Chrome, Skype etc in ubuntu?

Comment: @MohammadAli yes but you should google search what you are looking for.  if you can't find an answer then post another question here.  a quick google for "skype ubuntu" returns https://askubuntu.com/questions/775087/how-to-install-skype-in-ubuntu-16-04

If you feel I have answered your original question please accept this answer. as getting reputation for answering questions is what keeps this site going. (accept this answer by selecting the check mark next to the above answer)